# Carregar menu após login com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

No index.html tenho o ng-view onde o conteúdo HTML é carregado:

```
<body>
    <div ng-include src="'view/sidebar.html'" class="sidebar sidebar-left" toggleable parent-active-class="sidebar-left-in" id="mainSidebar"></div>
    <div ng-include src="'view/sidebarRight.html'" class="sidebar sidebar-right" toggleable parent-active-class="sidebar-right-in" id="rightSidebar"></div>
    <div class="app">
        <ng-view class="app-content"></ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
```

No mesmo index.html faço o include de 2 arquivos (sidebar.html e sidebarRight.html) conforme o código acima, porém esses arquivos só devem aparecer depois do login.

Na aplicação, após o login o utilizador é redirecionado para o dashboard.html, veja o route provider:

```
$routeProvider.
        //...
        .when('/dashboard', {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'view/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
//...
```

Já vi que não é permitido ter mais de um "ng-view", então como resolvo o problema?

Já tentei colocar os includes dentro do dashboard.html, porém teria que duplicar para várias páginas e no template que estou a utilizar, é mesmo necessário estar fora da div "app".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realmente o ng-view não é permitido duas vezes na mesma página. Mas pra resolver isso não é dificil, tudo que você precisa fazer é usar um módulo que foi desenvolvido exatamente para esse tipo de situação, aplicações de médio/grande porte que precisam de multiplas paginas com layouts diferentes e "nested content".

O módulo que resolve isso se chama [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#angularui-router-).

A configuração é muito simples e ele tem diversas funcionalidades. Eu criei um plunker onde você pode ver como é fácil configurar e usar. [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IRrhsn5cotemX8oczNKP?p=preview).

Você pode observar no código que no arquivo principal (index.html) vc vai encontrar duas divs com a diretiva ui-view.

```
<div ui-view="login"></div>
<div ui-view="dashboard"></div>
```

E vai encontrar essa mesma diretiva nos demais arquivos, o que significa que vc pode aninhar mais conteúdo conforme sua necessidade.